# Redux-toolkit usage with Typescript without state mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a React project which is using [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) in JavaScript. I'm trying to shift project to TypeScript for debugging ease and Type Safety benefits. My Slices code is as

```
export const entitiesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "entities",
    initialState: initialentitiesState,
    reducers: {
      // getentityById
      entityFetched: (state, action) => {
        state.actionsLoading = false;
        state.entityForEdit = action.payload.entityForEdit;
        state.error = null;
      },
      // findentities
      entitiesFetched: (state, action) => {
        const { totalCount, entities } = action.payload;
        state.listLoading = false;
        state.error = null;
        state.entities = entities;
        state.totalCount = totalCount;
      },
      // createentity
      entityCreated: (state, action) => {
        state.actionsLoading = false;
        state.error = null;
        state.entities.push(action.payload.entity);
      },
      // updateentity
      entityUpdated: (state, action) => {
        state.error = null;
        state.actionsLoading = false;
        state.entities = state.entities.map(entity => {
          if (entity.id === action.payload.entity.id) {
            return action.payload.entity;
          }
          return entity;
        });
      },
      // deleteentities
      entitiesDeleted: (state, action) => {
        state.error = null;
        state.actionsLoading = false;
        state.entities = state.entities.filter(
          el => !action.payload.ids.includes(el.id)
        );
      },
      }
    }
  });
```

But I think the assignment like this `state.somevar=updatedval` is doing state mutation which is not good. I want to declare my state Interface with readonly to avoid state mutation. I have gone through the [Redux-Toolkit-Usage-With-Typescript](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript), which I think should avoid state mutation but all code snippets seem to be doing state mutation. I want something like this

```
      entityFetched: (state, action) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          actionsLoading:false,
          entityForEdit:action.payload.entityForEdit,
          error:null
        }
      }
```

Please guide me if I'm missing something or misinterpretting the meaning of state mutation.
Any broader advice for using TypeScript with React would be most welcomed!
Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux Toolkit's `createReducer` and `createSlice` APIs use [the Immer library](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) internally, which allows you to write "mutating" syntax in your reducers, but turns that into safe and correct immutably updates.

Please read through [the new "Redux Essentials" core docs tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) for further explanations on how Redux relies on immutability, and how Immer makes it safe to write "mutations" in your reducers.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your great Answer! However, can I still write something like this using spread operator to recreate state object ......      return {
          ...state,
          actionsLoading:false,
          entityForEdit:action.payload.entityForEdit,
          error:null
        }

Comment: Yes. Immer allows you to _either_ mutate the existing state _or_ return an entirely new state, so you can still write a nested spread of some form if you really want to.